# how to convert data into nested dictionary in python,dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a large dataset of item code and component each item code correlate with component and further component become item code of another component. how can I make a nested `dictionary` in `python`

```
item code   component
a             q
b             w
c             r
d             t
e             y
q             u
q             v
```

desired output:-

```
{a:{q:[u,v]},b:w,c:r etc}
```

How can I achieve this nested `dictionary` in `python`, I have large data
I used `defaultdict` but it gave me only a `dictionary` not a nested  `dictionary`

Comment: This will require pandas+networkx

Comment: @Pygirl I've never used `networkx`. Can you show me how can this be done using `networkx`? Meanwhile, I'll try to do this in pure `python`.

Comment: how can I use networkx , I never use it

Comment: Check my answer this is the best I can try.

Comment: @MayankPorwal: Using networkx alone won't be helpful as you still have to postprocess the result  into the above given format. but yeah Networkx can help me to get paths as the tuples for each node which I can convert it into the above format.

Comment: Did you try out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [108]: df = pd.DataFrame({'item_code': list('abcdeqq'), 'component': list('qwrtyuv')})

In [109]: import networkx as nx

In [110]: g = nx.DiGraph([(k,v) for k,v in zip(df['item_code'], df['component'])])

In [111]: {k:v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k,v in nx.convert.to_dict_of_lists(g).items() if v}
Out[111]: {'a': 'q', 'q': ['u', 'v'], 'b': 'w', 'c': 'r', 'd': 't', 'e': 'y'}
```

Comment: this will be same as `df.groupby(['item_code'])['component'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Comment: ...or similar to `{a: [d for c,d in df.values if a==c] for a,b in df.values}` or even better but longer `{a: set(d for c,d in df.values if a==c) for a,b in df.values}`

Answer (score 0):

Using networkx you can get something like this. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41473389/6660373) I am able to reach to this solution:

```
import networkx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(df.values)

def comb_tup(li_tup):
    d = {}
    crnt = d  # memo the crnt subtree
    stck = []  # stack of (sub)trees along current path
    for k, v in li_tup:
        while stck and k not in crnt:
            crnt = stck.pop()
        if k not in crnt:
            crnt[k] = {}
        stck.append(crnt)
        crnt = crnt[k]
        crnt[v] = {}
    return d
    
final_di = {}
for node in G.nodes:
    vi = list(nx.dfs_edges(G,node))
    d = comb_tup(vi)
    if len(d.keys()):
        for k,v in d.items():
            final_di[k] = v
```

---

**final_di:**

```
{'a': {'q': {'u': {}, 'v': {}}},
 'q': {'u': {}, 'v': {}},
 'b': {'w': {}},
 'c': {'r': {}},
 'd': {'t': {}},
 'e': {'y': {}}}
```

If you have this data:

```
   item_code    component
0   a           q
1   b           w
2   c           r
3   d           t
4   e           y
5   q           u
6   q           v
7   u           x
```

---

**final_di:**

```
{'a': {'q': {'u': {'x': {}}, 'v': {}}},
 'q': {'u': {'x': {}}, 'v': {}},
 'b': {'w': {}},
 'c': {'r': {}},
 'd': {'t': {}},
 'e': {'y': {}},
 'u': {'x': {}}}
```